# setAttribute not working when trying to set value of input field

Tags: javascript

So I was implementing a simple form where if a user checks a checkbox it'll copy shipping name to billing name and if he unchecks it , the billing info will be erased.

the problem is when I try to set the value of billing name after erasing it once (by clicking on it again) the value from shipping info is not copied. I have been using the setAttribute function for this. I tried by using billingName.value = shippingName.value and it worked just fine.

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
 <head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    <title>Shipping and Billing</title> 
    <style>     
        input{          
          border:1px solid black;
    }       
        input:focus{
       background-color: #E6E6E6;       
        }
    fieldset{
       margin-bottom: 4%;
    }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>    
        <p>Add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form.  Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip.  If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>

        <form>      
        <fieldset>
      <legend>Shipping Information</legend>           
      <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>        
      <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "shippingName" required><br/>

      <label for = "shippingzip">Zip code:</label>        
      <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{6}" required><br/>
        </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>        
        <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>                        
        <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>              
    <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>       
    <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "billingName" required><br/>
       
        <label for = "billingzip">Zip code:</label>       
        <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
    </fieldset>

    <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JS

```
//alert(shippingZip.value);
//alert('value');
function billingFunction(){
    var shippingName = document.getElementById('shippingName');
    var shippingZip = document.getElementById('shippingZip');
    var billingName = document.getElementById('billingName');
    var billingZip = document.getElementById('billingZip');
    check = document.getElementById('same');
    if(check.checked==true){
        alert(shippingName.value);
        billingName.setAttribute('value', shippingName.value);
        //billingName.value = shippingName.value;
        billingZip.setAttribute('value',shippingZip.value);
    }
    else{
        billingName.value = "";
        billingZip.setAttribute('value','');
    }



}
```

Can somebody please explain this weird behavior of JS?

EDIT: it seems the problem is in my if else block if I set my billingName value using setAttribute and also remove it using setAttribute it'll work fine but if I change any one of these functions by using var.value = "text", it wont work.

That's weird

EDIT2:

So both my update should either be setAttribute or var.value otherwise it will go wonky. can somebody please explain this behavior?

Comment: `billingName.value = whatever` is all you need, there's no need to use `setAttribute()`.

Comment: I know that, but I'm trying to experiment with js as I'm a beginner

Comment: First remove all the extra spaces around the = signs in your HTML, it's not proper semantics.

Comment: `.setAttribute()` doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript; it's a browser API. It is not necessary and, as you've found, doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @NathanielFlick what??? That is not good advice, and that opinion aside it has *nothing* to do with "semantics". It's perfectly OK to include spaces around `=` in HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: The value attribute is only used by browser when a form control is rendered so it knows what the initial value is. After that it will not be the same as the value *property* when user or code makes changes to the property

Comment: @charlietfl is there any doc where I could refer to it in more detail?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Ok @Pointy maybe it's just my detail orientedness, sorry. :) There are two semantic errors but they have to do with the labels not being properly linked to their fields with fors. My first instinct is to always try to get things straight with the HTML before diagnosing an issue, seems sensible, yes?

Comment: Sure, I agree, but for example `=` without spaces in JavaScript makes me feel like I'm trapped in a closet, however I generally use spaces around `=` in HTML for clarity; it makes no sense, maybe, but that's how coding style opinions always work I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `setAttribute()` to modify certain attributes, most notably `value` in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the properties. For example, use `Element.value` instead of `Element.setAttribute()`

```
if(check.checked==true){
    alert(shippingName.value);
    billingName.value = shippingName.value;
    billingZip.value = shippingZip.value;
}
else{
    billingName.value = "";
    billingZip.value = '';
}
```

Comment: already did it. I know this will work, what I want to know why is setAttribute so weird

Comment: Using `setAttribute()` to modify certain attributes, most notably `value` in XUL, works inconsistently, as the attribute specifies the default value. To access or modify the current values, you should use the properties. For example, use `Element.value` instead of `Element.setAttribute()`.

Comment: @Prince To directly engage with OP's question, you could include in your answer a link to documentation that either explains why this is the behavior, or at least states that it is.